# How to Upgrade magento version from 2.3.x to 2.3.x [Enterprise Edition]

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2.3, magento-enterprise, magento-upgrade

How to Upgrade magento version from 2.3.x to 2.3.x [Enterprise Edition]

- Steps to successfully update Magento 2.3.x to 2.3.x [EE]

Answer (score 2):

***Here are the steps I used to successfully update Magento 2.3.3 [EE] to
2.3.5 [EE] I have divided the steps into parts:***

***Follow The URL:*** [Here are the steps to upgrade Magento 2.3.x to 2.3.x](https://roshanyadav007.wordpress.com/2020/09/29/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-3-x-ee-to-2-3-x-ee/)

**Upgrade Magento 2 using composer: -**

- Backup code and database

- Backup the composer.json & index.php file.

- cp composer.json composer.json.bak
- cp index.php index.php.bak
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
- php bin/magento cache:disable
- php bin/magento maintenance:enable
- composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.5 --no-update

**--> Message :** ./composer.json has been updated.

- composer update

**--> PHP Fatal error:**

> Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PRE_COMMAND_RUN' in
> /var/www/html/m23x/ontime/vendor/laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin/src/DependencyRewriterPlugin.php:63

**--> composer --version**

**--> Solution:**

- It's just because of the composer's old version, you need to install the new version (composer version >= Composer 1.9.1)
- composer update
- rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**Error:**
Element 'route': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( resources ).

**Solution:**
Magento_MysqlMq [disable this module]

- php bin/magento setup:di:compile

**Errors:**

1. Fatal error:  Declaration of

> Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\NodeList::item($index):
> ?Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\ElementInterface must be
> compatible with
> Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\NodeListInterface::item(int
> $index): ?Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\Adapter\ElementInterface in
> /var/www/html/m23x/ontime/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php
> on line 19

**Solution:**

> vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php (On line 47
> change as follows) public function item(int $index): ?ElementInterface

- php bin/magento cache:enable
- php bin/magento maintenance:disable
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
- service varnish restart [If you use Varnish for page caching, restart it.]
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

> SUCCESSFULLY UPGRADED - MAGENTO 2.3.3 To MAGENTO 2.3.5 [EE]

**replace OLD index.php file**

- rm -rf var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/* pub/static/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

**You may face the below issue at the time of deploying.**

**1) Error:**

> The contents from the
> "/var/www/html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js"
> file can't be read. Warning!
>
> file_get_contents(/var/www/html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-min-resolver.min.js):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

**Solution:**
Disable Minify CSS / JS OR JS/CSS Merge

- php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0
- php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0
- php bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0
- php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0
- php bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

- php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
- chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/
- service varnish restart

+++++++++++++++++++++++

**Checkout page errors:--**

1. Magento 2.3.4 Checkout Infinite loop detected.

Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path.

Bug in Code File of 2.3.5

**Message:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php line 240 code is a
> bug On line 240 we have the code: if ($this->isLoading) { ... which
> throw this exception. The private member $isLoading is set to false by
> default and is only set to true on line number 243 in the Session.php
> the code will never reach this line as the Quote is not already
> created and need to be created at line number 244 but we are throwing
> an error on line 241 which breaks the script. No matter what we select
> in the payment method the code always breaks.

**Temp Solution:**

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php Try to replace this
> file with version 2.3.3 and try to checkout again.

+++++++++++

**Note:**
Vendor file changes as follows below.

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php

> vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Dom/NodeList.php

***If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.***

Comment: https://wp.me/p4FAWA-6X

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the dev docs on upgrading. It has its own section [Upgrading from Open Source to Commerce](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#manage-packages). They give example commands and everything. Just swap out the version numbers for the one you want to change to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have posted my answer which I used/followed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set up a whole new store on Magento Enterprise and then import all your important data from Community edition.