# How to update Magento 2.3 to 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, upgrade, magento2.4

I have a store in Magento 2.x.x

I want to update Magento 2.3 to 2.4 but when I update it using the command:

> composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update

I get the following errors:

```
Warning from repo.magento.com: Your Magento authentication keys are invalid. Please double-check your keys in your Marketplace account. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
Warning from repo.magento.com: Your Magento authentication keys are invalid. Please double-check your keys in your Marketplace account. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
Warning from repo.magento.com: Your Magento authentication keys are invalid. Please double-check your keys in your Marketplace account. For instructions, visit https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html
Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

I have my keys but where to put these keys is an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento 2 root directory of the project rename **auth.json.sample** file to **auth.json** OR create **auth.json** file and add Keys mentioned below.

Format as follows below:-

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<username>",
            "password": "<password>"
        }
    }
}
```

If the above solution not worked try the below one.

Add keys on system **auth.json** file path as follows below

```
vim /root/.composer/auth.json
```

For Magento 2 upgrade steps as follows --> https://wp.me/p4FAWA-6X

OR

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/323229/85990

If you like the answer please give thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

the Magento keys should be added in a file called `auth.json` in the `.composer` folder (which is situated in the root folder of your magento project), the file content format is:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<user>",
            "password": "<pass>"
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `<user>` with the public key and `<pass>` with the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Magento server and enter the following command

```
composer config --list | grep home
```

This will tell you where the composer home folder is configured i.e.

```
[home] /home/someuser/.composer
```

Add your correctly configured `auth.json` file to the composer home folder

```
/home/someuser/.composer/auth.json
```

If you want to change the composer home folder you can manually set the `COMPOSER_HOME` environment variable, this is best done before composer is installed...

```
export COMPOSER_HOME=/var/www/dev/.composer
```