# Cannot download from magentocommerce.com with pub and prive keys?

Tags: magento2

I cannot seem to download Magento with my keys. Is it me or my account? Or is it a general issue?

```
https://<pub>:<private>@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/file/Magento-CE-2.4.0.tar.gz
```

I tried different keys. I also swapped their places just to be sure. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to download this via CLI like this before, but it doesn't work for me either. I am not sure this is supposed to work like this anyway.

However, I recommend downloading it via composer and use your keys in an auth.json files [as explained here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/330358/how-to-update-magento-2-3-to-2-4/330364#330364). Or you could login to magento.com and download the archive directly from browser [as mentioned here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download).

Comment: I think it should. Check this page: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html. This should also work: `curl -k https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/help` Does this work for you?

Comment: nope. is it a special requirement of your project to use it like this? you could just simply use the `composer create-project` command from CLI.

Comment: No, actually I am debugging a community project. I think I am just going to wait for an answer to the opened issue on Github. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solved. I was using the wrong key pair. Apparently it should be MAG id and access token. This is something different then a public and private key pair. Although both are generated in the Magento.com dashboard. If using the right ones the url works and one can download ZIP packages of any release.

Comment: Glad you sorted this out! I suggest you add this info as an answer and mark the question as solved.